# Custom UIView; do stuff when view's size is below certain trash-hold

Tags: swift, uiview, size, swift5

I have a custom view that I add dynamically to another (image)view that is within a scrollview. Therefor the image size will vary based upon the (initial) zoomscale of the scrollView.
So, basicly I want to set some properties and constraints when thsi view has been added to the (image)View. I thought this could be handled on didMoveToSuperView(), but frame and bounds are always 0??

How to solve this?

My custom View:

```
//MARK: - Properties
    private var annotation: Annotation!
    
    private var pinImageView = UIImageView()
    private var completedImageView = UIImageView()
    private var arrowImageView = UIImageView()
    private var pinTitleLabel = ProjectTitleLabel(withTextAlignment: .center, andFont: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .callout), andColor: .label)
    
    //MARK: - Init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required convenience init(with annotation: Annotation) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        self.annotation = annotation
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    
    //MARK: - Configure view
    private func configure() {
        (...)
    }
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        print("HERE: \(self.frame.height)", bounds.height, intrinsicContentSize)
        //Compensate for when the pin view becomes really small (on very low res images)
        if self.bounds.height <= 40 {
            pinTitleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.45
            pinTitleLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
            pinTitleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12).isActive = true
            print("SMALL")
        } else {
            pinTitleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
            print("NORMAL")
        }
    }
}
```

and the code that adds this view:

```
    var annotation: Annotation? {
        didSet {
            //remove any previous pin
            mapImageLocationPin?.removeFromSuperview()

            if let location = annotation?.location {
                //Activate the corresponding Map Image and update picker
                selectedMapImage = location.map
                mapImagePickerView.selectRow(mapImagesController.getRowFor(location.map), inComponent: 0, animated: true)

                //Instantiate new Pin with annotation
                mapImageLocationPin = MapImageLocationPin(with: annotation!)
                mapImageView.addSubview(mapImageLocationPin!)

                //Desired height and width
                let desiredWidth: CGFloat = 160
                let desiredHeight: CGFloat = 80
                
                //compensate for scrollView zoomscale, but never bigger than desired width & height!
                let width = min(desiredWidth, desiredWidth / mapImageScrollView.minimumZoomScale)
                let height = min(desiredHeight, desiredHeight / mapImageScrollView.minimumZoomScale)
                print("w: \(width) x h: \(height)")
                
                //center the pin image horizontal on location
                let y = location.coordinateY
                let x = location.coordinateX - (width / 2)
                
                //position (frame) the pin
                mapImageLocationPin?.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `viewDidLayoutSubviews` ?

Comment: That's a method on a viewController, not accessible from within my custom view ...

Comment: My bad, have you tried `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Yes, there bounds and frame are not nil! Thanks